# How can I track users and other web stats in a Perl CGI program?

Tags: perl, cgi

I have this internal website within a company and it's Perl CGI based. I would like to install some kind of system to track users and other web statistics.

Any recommendations on how to do this? I would like to have full control and allow easy to install.

Comment: Track users? Keep statistics on what?

Comment: There's a [StackExchange site for webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) now. Since it's a targeted site, you might get better answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is most advanced web statistics program that I know. It is easy to install and to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/)